# Steps to deploy a Quarkus app with Rancher Rio

Tags: quarkus, rancher, rancher-rio

Have anyone tried to install Rio and also deploy a Quarkus application on it?

- What are the steps in deploying a Quarkus app with Rio?

Rio:
https://rio.io/